# How do I let my JavaScript file affect an EJS variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I defined an ejs variable in my index.ejs file called "complete" and checks if a user has filled out a journal using the following:

```
<% if (complete == false) { %>
   <button class="new_journal">Fill Out Journal<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  
<% } else { %>
    <div class="new_journal2">You Already Filled Out Your Journal</div>
<% }% >
```

In my JavaScript file, I made the following function to countdown 24 hours, and then change the value of "complete" to false:

```
var hour = 23;
var minutes = 59; 
var seconds  = 60;
var value = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    var time = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Hours: " + hour + 
    " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds;
    seconds -= 1;

    if(seconds == 0) {
        minutes -= 1;
        seconds = 60;
    };

    if(minutes == 0) {
        hour -= 1;
        minutes = 60;
    };

    if(hours == 0) {
        complete = false;    
    }

}, 1000);
```

However, when the timer reaches 0, it doesn't change the value of complete.

Comment: I do not use ejs, but I am guessing that ejs does not magically update when variables change. And note setTimeout is horrible for clocks/timers since it is not accurate.

Comment: The above comment is correct. EJS is only updated by server side code and is only evaluated once per render. You do not have access to, nor can you change the EJS variables in your JavaScript. You'd have to update the template manually in your JS file.

Comment: @AustinEzell How does one update the template in their JS file? :P

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up Client side javascript and EJS in a wrong way. 
As per your code the javascript you have mentioned runs at client side and the EJS code you mentioned will run at Server side so at that moment it can't read complete variable value.

I see you have a date value in #timer so i hope you have that data server side some where, use that to derive the complete variable value at server side instead client side.